# Problem with the relationship in express/mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Im creating a document named 'Sells', each sell has properties such as date, name, total, the id of the user who created it ect. and I have another document named 'Sell_details' where I store the details of each sell with their sell _id. So how do i retrieve all the sells i have in the database with an array of the details which that sell has? I've tried to do it but it doesn't retrieve all the details and among other problems. Here's what i have.

this is the sell model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
 
const ventaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    usuarioId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    clienteId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    tipo_comprobante: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    num_comprobante: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    serie_comprobante: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    fecha: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    impuesto: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    total: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    estado: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Activo'
    },
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    ventas: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Detalle_Venta'
    },
    detalles: {
        type: Array
    }
},{ toJSON: { virtuals: true } });
```

ventaSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, { message: 'Expected {PATH} to be unique' });

const Venta = mongoose.model('Venta', ventaSchema);

module.exports = Venta;

his is the sell router:

```
router.get('/ventas', auth, async(req, res) => {
    try {
        await req.user.populate({
            path: 'ventas',
            options: {
                limit: req.query.limit
            }
        }).execPopulate();
 
        req.user.ventas.forEach(element => {
            const detalles = Detalle_Venta.find({ventaId: element._id});
            detalles.then(el => {
                el.forEach(detalle => {
                    if (element.detalles.length > 1) {
                        element.detalles.forEach(el => {
                            const isAdded = el._id === detalle._id;
                            if (isAdded) {
                                element.detalles.push(detalle);
                            }
                        })
                    } else {
                        element.detalles.push(detalle);
                    }
                });
                });
                element.save();
        });
        res.send(req.user.ventas);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error);
    }
 
});
```

and this is the output from postman:

```
[
    {
        "fecha": "2020-06-22T18:16:44.175Z",
        "estado": "Activo",
        "detalles": [
            {
                "_id": "5ef0fa4e49de0641c46eca0b",
                "idArticulo": "5ee825bfb3da101df49822ae",
                "cantidad": 30,
                "precio": 2,
                "descuento": 0,
                "ventaId": "5ef0fa4e49de0641c46eca0a",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5ef0fa4e49de0641c46eca0b",
                "idArticulo": "5ee825bfb3da101df49822ae",
                "cantidad": 30,
                "precio": 2,
                "descuento": 0,
                "ventaId": "5ef0fa4e49de0641c46eca0a",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "_id": "5ef0fa4e49de0641c46eca0a",
        "usuarioId": "5ee3b6b50376d7143c476834",
        "clienteId": "5ee6b115e43839274cc50ddb",
        "tipo_comprobante": "RNC",
        "num_comprobante": 1000000,
        "serie_comprobante": 20001,
        "impuesto": 18,
        "total": 10500,
        "owner": "5ef0e64083f8c815cc67cd7c",
        "__v": 2,
        "id": "5ef0fa4e49de0641c46eca0a"
    },
    {
        "fecha": "2020-06-22T18:16:44.175Z",
        "estado": "Activo",
        "detalles": [
            {
                "_id": "5ef0fa5a49de0641c46eca0d",
                "idArticulo": "5ee825bfb3da101df49822ae",
                "cantidad": 30,
                "precio": 2,
                "descuento": 0,
                "ventaId": "5ef0fa5a49de0641c46eca0c",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5ef0fa5a49de0641c46eca0e",
                "idArticulo": "5ee825bfb3da101df49822ae",
                "cantidad": 303,
                "precio": 2,
                "descuento": 0,
                "ventaId": "5ef0fa5a49de0641c46eca0c",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "_id": "5ef0fa5a49de0641c46eca0c",
        "usuarioId": "5ee3b6b50376d7143c476834",
        "clienteId": "5ee6b115e43839274cc50ddb",
        "tipo_comprobante": "RNC",
        "num_comprobante": 1000000,
        "serie_comprobante": 20001,
        "impuesto": 18,
        "total": 10500,
        "owner": "5ef0e64083f8c815cc67cd7c",
        "__v": 1,
        "id": "5ef0fa5a49de0641c46eca0c"
    }
]
```

Before you say i did it, the first array of the  'detalles' array (which stores the sell details of that sell), i  added one sell detail and i'm getting two, and the second array of the other sell, i'm getting two sell details but i added 3 and if i add 4 i'm only getting 2 and i don't know why. is there a way to fix it and another best way to do it ?

Comment: this is a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

mongoose has a powerful aggregation operator called populate which you have used.
You should use type ObjectId to the property sell details.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const personSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

const storySchema = Schema({
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  title: String,
  fans: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
});
```

Then you create the author and story linking them up

```
 const author = new Person({
   _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
   name: 'Ian Fleming',
   age: 50
 });

author.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);



 const story1 = new Story({
    title: 'Casino Royale',
    author: author._id    // assign the _id from the person
  });



story1.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    // that's it!
    });
});
```

You can thereafter populate

```
Story.
findOne({ title: 'Casino Royale' }).
  populate('author').
  exec(function (err, story) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log('The author is %s', story.author.name);
    // prints "The author is Ian Fleming"
});
```

This will ensure you don't get an entry twice..